# Chrome Autolock

Tags: google-chrome, security, password-protection

When you add a supervised user in Chrome (tick box to check when adding a user) you then have an option "Exit and Childlock" asking your password when you restart Chrome. Very useful, especially with 2 factor authentication. Is there a way to schedule a task on Windows to perform the "Exit and Childlock" even if chrome is closed ? That  way I can stayed logged on all day long in my employer's computer and I know that when I leave my Chrome is locked. (and hopefuly quite encrypted).